# How much sleep time is good for 2 threads running simultaneously

Tags: java, multithreading, performance

I am writing code to read a large JSON file and write data in database. I am spinning 2 threads, one to read from file (mixed mode of steam and object reading one by one using Gson) placing object into a blocking queue and second thread reads data from queue and save into db using batch size of 1000.
I didn't put any sleep timer in thread 1, on the other hand thread 2 is using sleep (200) just before saving data.

I was wondering if it will be helpful to put a sleep of 10-20 miliseconds in thread 1 too?
Does it help performance wise switching between threads by using sleep?

Comment: Why do you use `sleep()` at all? What is the purpose?

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say anything about performance without running benchmarks, but... in principle, you shouldn't need to `sleep()` at all (the producer will block if the queue is full, the consumer if it's empty).

You can use `yield()` to hint that the current thread reached a point where it might be a good idea to switch to another one.

Comment: `yield()` should be used with caution. Javadoc says `The scheduler is free to ignore this hint.`

Comment: No, it doesn't: "to hint" means "to suggest" :-)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have just one core? Or are other cores busy? Otherwise, just drop the sleep, you don't need it.

Even with a single core, you don't need `sleep`. Let your parser `put` *whole batches* in the queue, let your DB writer `take` them. I'd go for a queue size of two, so that the DB improbably idles needlessly.

As the JDBC connection is synchronous, the DB writer probably spends most time waiting for the transaction commit.

Comment: There are 4 cores and this code is running as a part of batch job. There will be other batch jobs running too at the same time. I just want to give each thread enough time to process so that data can be read write in parallel. Queue size does't really matter as ASA reader (no sleep() call) puts an object into queue, writer consumes it and save into memory to meet the batch size. you really made a point about jdbc connection. I do one run by removing sleep() from writer and see if there was any difference performance wise.

Comment: @vermap I'd really let the parser do the batching, as it means less communication via the queue (though the queue is pretty efficient). `Sleep` might be useful, if you want the other unrelated threads run more, but otherwise, there's no point.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a Java developer, but the principles are same.

1. Don't use sleeps.
2. Use producer-consumer pattern.

In producer-consumer pattern 1st thread (producer) reads data from JSON as fast as possible and putting them to thread safe queue from which 2nd thread (consumer) reads them.

Simplified algorithm.

Producer thread.

1. Read data from JSON file.
2. Write read data to queue.
3. Set synchronization event to notify consumer thread.
4. Go to 1.

Consumer thread.

1. Wait until synchronization event is set.
2. Read data from queue.
3. Save data to DB.
4. If queue is non-empty go to 2 else go to 1.

The producer-consumer is a well known pattern, so it's not hard to find same examples in Java. For instance look [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/producer-consumer-solution-using-threads-java/).

Answer (score 0):

None. You should not rely on sleep to ensure multiple threads interact correctly. They should instead use synchronization,  locks, buffers (queues, especially finite length queues) to ensure correct operation.